# How do I get the actual resource from a ComponentResourceKey?

Tags: wpf, componentresourcekey

I have a ComponentResourceKey defined in my resource dictionary like this:

```
<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:Resources}, ResourceId=BaseControlStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,4,0,0" />
</Style>
```

I have a static class that I use as a shortcut to provide the resource keys liek this:

```
public class Resources
{
    public static ComponentResourceKey BaseControlStyleKey
    {
        get
        {
            return new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(Resources), "BaseControlStyle");
        }
    }
}
```

Now typically when I use this style I do something like this:

```
<TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:Resources.BaseControlStyleKey}}"/>
```

However, I have a scenario where I need to set a style in code like this:

```
myTextBox.Style = Resources.BaseControlStyleKey // Does not work.
```

Any ideas how I extract the style from the ComponentResourceKey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
myTextBox.Style = 
        Application.Current.TryFindResource(Resources.BaseControlStyleKey)
        as Style;
```

Answer (score 1):

After you have created a separate ComponentResourceKey holder (Resources class) you can simplify your key declaration.

**Instead of:**

```
<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:Resources}, ResourceId=BaseControlStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,4,0,0" />
</Style>
```

**You can simply use:**

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static local:Resources.BaseControlStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,4,0,0" />
</Style>
```